# Google maps API divide destinations to groups and find shortest paths

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, google-maps

I'm about to write a project in C# MVC and AngularJS. In this project I have a list of about 100-200 locations that I need to divide into groups, each group 3-4 destinations max. The groups are divided in a way that the destinations in them are minimal. Then have to build routes from a single origin into each group (seperate route for each group).
I'm kinda new to the google maps api and got lost in it, is there a service that gets multiple destinations and retrieves the minimum distance between them all? 
Or I must find it in my algorithm by looping on all destinations?
All that I've found was distance matrix between origin and single destination.

Comment: I've done something like this before, you'll have to loop all of them and then determine the minimum distance. Keep in mind that google API has a limit to how many subsequent requests you can make, it may be better to just to calculate the distance in a straight line by using the lon/lat of the locations.

Comment: @George do you remember what that limit is?

Comment: Not too sure, but it should say in the documentation.

Comment: @George Found it, 2,500 elements... should be sufficient to run it one time and save in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Distance matrix API has different limitations on number of destinations and number of origins but however the total element limit (element is considered as combination of one origin and one destination) is 625 (you can have any number of origins and any number of destinations but their product shouldn't go over 625) per call.

That being said you can implement your call as single origin and 625 destinations per call. There is also another limit for google distance matrix which limits you to request only 1000 elements per second.

The response can be either XML or JSON based upon your specification and can take either lat/Long values or an address.
[Google Distance matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro)